# How to diagnose Xcode errors

Tags: xcode, swift

I have been using Xcode recently a lot, however, every so often I'll inexplicably receive error messages about perfectly innocuous components of my code. I'd like to know how one diagnose these because as you can see in the buttom right of the screenshot, there's no log entry to go off of. Thanks.

Here's my screen shot: 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: There's no error message in that screenshot. You put in a breakpoint, and it stopped execution when it hit the breakpoint.

Comment: show us the original error message and we'll help you out

Comment: Step one towards diagnosing these error messages would be to take note of their contents.

Comment: Look at the blue tick on the left, in the gutter: it's a breakpoint. It looks like you didn't set it on purpose, so delete it by grabbing it out of the gutter.

Comment: Does this help? Not sure where to look: http://i1087.photobucket.com/albums/j461/niiooo/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-01%20at%2010.01.50%20AM.png

Comment: That doesn't really give much information... @NioPullus did you set the breakpoint on purpose?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Xcode so I'm not totally familiar with what "setting a breakpoint" involves but I'm going to say no. I agree with you, there's really no information and this is why I'm confused about to diagnose this type of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you have accidentally set a "breakpoint" in your code. You set a breakpoint by clicking on the left margin. A breakpoint stops your code automatically when it reaches that point.

Since you commented out the inside of the `goBack()` function, it stops at the first line of uncommented code.

The breakpoint you set is the little blue line to the left of the line `self.scoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()`. To get rid of it, click it and drag it into the main area of your code.